# Switch Linux Distros

Tags: kubuntu, mint

how to switch linux distros without loosing data. I am using Kubuntu kde plasma and it stucks sometimes. For gaming it is not good.

Comment: You just re-install over your existing system using the "*Manual Partitioning*" or "*Something-else*" option with Ubuntu (or flavors), select your wanted partitions & do **not** format.  However only Ubuntu and official flavors of Ubuntu are on-topic here so what I said will apply only to Ubuntu and official flavors of Ubuntu (it may not apply for non-Ubuntu; which may not use *di*, `ubiquity` or `calamares` installers, or use modified versions of same).  For questions relating to Mint you'll need to ask on a Mint forum, or SE's Unix & Linux site, see https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? What do you think a good fit would be to you? I believe that it might be possible to adjust your current distro to have a better gaming experience.

Comment: You don't need to reinstall to install a different desktop (Xubuntu, Lubuntu, etc.). You can install multiple desktops in one installation. This makes it easy to try them out to see which one works best.

Answer (score 3):

If KDE Kubuntu gets stuck sometimes, you can install a different, more lightweight desktop environment without reinstalling the entire operating system. You can have multiple desktop environments installed and you choose your desktop environment on your login screen.

To install a new desktop environment to your existing Ubuntu installation, run the following commands:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install tasksel
sudo tasksel
```

Now, you can select a desktop from the list. **Do not choose any of the "LIVE CD" or "CD" options**.

ONLY choose from the **desktop** or **minimal**. If any of the other options are already chosen, leave them alone and do not un-select these.

**NOTE:** [because of a bug in tasksel](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/tasksel/+bug/1779645), DO NOT use tasksel to uninstall packages. ONLY use tasksel to install.

Some good lightweight options are [Xubuntu](https://xubuntu.org/), [Lubuntu](https://lubuntu.me/), and possibly [Ubuntu Mate](https://ubuntu-mate.org/). Lubuntu has a QT (LXQT) and a GTK (LXDE) version available. Both Xubuntu and Lubuntu have "minimal" versions that are even more lightweight.

The GTK version of Lubuntu may not be available on Ubuntu 19.10+

Since you are already running KDE, you may want to go with the Lubuntu QT option or Lubuntu minimal QT as KDE runs on QT so those dependencies will already be installed. The Lubuntu QT version is lightweight, runs fast, and is designed to run on desktops with limited resources so you can allocate more resources to gaming. However, Xubuntu and Lubuntu GTK are also lightweight and designed to run on limited resources. Ubuntu Mate is lightweight and runs on GTK as well.

[UbuntuStudio](https://ubuntustudio.org/) (which is based on the same XFCE desktop as Xubuntu) is also designed to use less resources and is centered around music production and graphic design. However, UbuntuStudio contains a lot of added music and graphics production software which may not fit your needs.

Use your arrow keys to navigate and <kbd>SPACE BAR</kbd> to select. When you are done, use the <kbd>TAB</kbd> key to highlight "OK" and then press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>.

After installing the new software, you will have to logout or reboot and then you can select which desktop environment to use from your login screen settings.

Keep in mind, that the login or "display-manager" screen may change when you do this. If you don't like your new login screen, you can always change back by selecting a different display manager (usually by running `sudo dpkg-reconfigure sddm` and then select the desired display-manager from that screen following the instructions). GTK based desktops like Xubuntu usually use Lightdm whereas QT desktops like Kubuntu and Lubuntu QT use SDDM.

However, if you choose Lubuntu QT, you can [select the SDDM theme](https://askubuntu.com/questions/871031/how-to-change-login-screen-sddm-on-kde-plasma-5) through your KDE desktop settings: System Settings > Startup and Shutdown > Login Screen (SDDM). The default Kubuntu SDDM theme is called "Breeze" and the Lubuntu SDDM theme is called: "Lubuntu chooser".

Comment: Is there a particular benefit to using tasksel over, for example, `sudo apt install xubuntu-desktop`. Re. `sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm`, Lubuntu 19.04+ and Kubuntu use SDDM.

Comment: @JusticeforMonica Yes, because the selection of desktops is presented in an easily understood format. For example, `apt-cache search desktop | grep desktop` returns 362 results whereas `tasksel` only shows a handful and also lists core "minimal" versions without any guesswork. Also, thanks for the tip about SDDM.