# Config multi display in lockscreen

Tags: kubuntu, multiple-monitors, display

I have an Asus VivoBook S532FL, when I boot Kubuntu 20.04, the lock screen shown in screenpad, and the config of the display are wrong, I mean when I move left to right it's move cursor up to the bottom

I fix screenpad problem in Kubuntu environment by config multi display in setting, I can disable screenpad too but it doesn't affect on boot and lockscreen

how can I config multi display for lock screen?

Comment: Please provide release details, and by lock screen do you mean `sddm` (ie. where you enter your username/password before logging in and using KDE).  Possibly useful could be https://askubuntu.com/questions/871031/how-to-change-login-screen-sddm-on-kde-plasma-5

Comment: kubuntu 20.4, that link didn't help me to config my second display(screenpad)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally by putting following config to `/usr/share/sddm/scripts/Xsetup` you can turn screen pad off:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

# to find display
# xrandr | grep ' connected'

# Xsetup - run as root before the login dialog appears

if [ -e /sbin/prime-offload ]; then
    echo running NVIDIA Prime setup /sbin/prime-offload
    /sbin/prime-offload
fi
xrandr --output HDMI-1 --off
xrandr --output eDP-1 --mode 1920x1080 --pos 0x0 --rotate normal
xrandr --output HDMI-1-1 --off
xrandr --output eDP-1-1 --mode 1920x1080 --pos 0x0 --rotate normal
```