# How to change SDDM login screen after sleep?

Tags: kubuntu, plasma-5, sddm

I tried looking at this question but it doesn't address my problem: [How to change login screen sddm on KDE Plasma 5](https://askubuntu.com/questions/871031/how-to-change-login-screen-sddm-on-kde-plasma-5)

I'm able to install new SDDM login screens (I'm using Kubuntu 20.04) using the Plasma options menu [Sytem Settings-->Startup and Shutdown-->Login Screen (SDDM)]. However, the new screen only appears when I first boot up or when I log out of my current user.

Most often I simply put the computer to sleep and then wake it back up to log in. When I do, the newly installed theme doesn't display, but instead the default screen that Kubuntu installed with. Is this expected behavior? I don't see any separate settings for "initial login" versus "login after sleep" or something similar. But clearly SDDM is treating these two situations differently.

I would like to be able to customize both screens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"But clearly SDDM is treating these two situations differently" - SDDM is a display manager and only involved in the initial login. The lock screen is part of the plasma desktop, so you'll have to look for a plasma theme that has a lock screen matching your SDDM theme.

Comment: I didn't realize the lock screen was set separately. For anyone else looking, on the System Settings menu it's under "Workspace Behavior-->Screen Locking-->Appearance".